# When is using reflection a good practice?

Tags: java, reflection

I recently learned about reflection in my course and was given an assignment to create objects from an XML file using reflection in Java. Through searching this site I'm noticing there seems to be a general consensus that using reflection, particularly in this way, is a bad idea. Odd to me because we were told this is one of the most useful things we'll learn this semester.

I have no control over my assignment so I'll just have to complete it this way anyhow. But I was wondering, when is using reflection a good practice? And what are some industry examples you might have where reflection was the best way to go about a problem?

Comment: JAXB(a java standard for xml parsing) relies on reflection, where did you find that it's bad ? I searched the Site, what I found were for specific scenarios :)

Comment: It is generally a bad idea to use reflection is *application code*, because you lose the strict type checking of the language. Reflection is generally for use by *framework code*, where it is essential. Good vs bad are not absolutes, but must be assessed in context.

Comment: Yeah, each time you write "reflection" in StackOverflow you risk being downvoted. Despite the fact that many of the most popular Java libraries are unavoidably based on some use of reflection. There is a good thread [here](http://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/193526/is-it-a-bad-habit-to-overuse-reflection)  on the topic.

Comment: I cite from the [tutorials](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/): `Reflection is powerful, but should not be used indiscriminately. If it is possible to perform an operation without using reflection, then it is preferable to avoid using it.` It is not bad per se and frameworks heavily based on this. Reflection may bypass the compiler save feature of Java (ex. setting final members).

Comment: Oh I see. Thank you. Yes it did seem to be frowned upon in this particular scenario. We aren't allowed to use JAXB for the assignment either. I struggled to see how useful it might be in our specific context.

Comment: I'm using it right now to implement a simple XML over HTTP remote procedure call, I tried to use Jackson for this but I was really creating to much bolierplate code (because of the structure chosen for the XML) so I started my little reflection based custom protocol..

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Reflection is a tool, you should use it when you need it, an use others where more appropriate.

When is appropriate to use reflection? When you are dealing with instance of object or classes which have some common behavior which is not enforced by interfaces.

The simplest example is POJO, you very often use classes which are just a collection of fields and their getter and setter, they much behave in the same manner, but you cannot define their common behavior with inheritance.

There are hundreds of tools that leverage that behavior building pojos from scratch, or setting fields, and they use reflection.

Examples: GSON, JAXB, Hibernate, Spring, Weld ... etc.

Reflection is more difficult to write, more difficult to debug, and test, give you pretty scary and uninformative stack traces, but let you deal with more general common behavior then inheritance.

*A side note*, since the introduction of annotations reflection has become less scary, because you can *decorate* classes with information that let you do reflection with a more reliable approach, in fact all the framework I cited use annotations.

Last but not least, you don't use reflection much all the same, because you need it for *meta programming* and, most of the time, *meta programming* has been done for you by others (see GSON, JAXB, Hibernate, Spring, Weld ... etc), so in fact you will find difficult to find a problem general enough to be solved with reflection, and has not been solved by others.

Answer (score 3):

Java has a lot of safety measures built into the code such as dong static type checking at compile time, private members, and final members.

While there are times where that is great but it is also very dangerous. Typically a member is declared private and/or final for a reason.

So yes reflection is often discouraged because you should not be disabling safeties unless you really need to.

Your homework is a lot like a JSON parser (e.g. GSON, Jackson, etc). They create dynamic object from JSON using reflections. I use a JSON parser in almost every project I work on, but I don't write nearly as much reflection myself.

So in conclusion while you should avoid reflections unless needed this homework will teach you two tings.
1. How reflection works in the case that you do *need* to use it.
2. A deeper understanding of how tools you use (e.g. GSON) work, so you can know how the sausage is made.

If you are studying Computer Science you will most likely have a class or two on data structures. While most projects you really should not build your own LinkedList (Java's is almost certainly better, at least better tested) building your own teaches you how the sausage is made so you know when to follow the rules and when to break them.